# Want to hide image in md view and show it in xs view in carousal?

Tags: carousel

want to hide image in md view and show it in xs view in carousal , i used hidden-md and hidden xs , using this i am able to hide image but for that image its showing dots and next ,prev symbol (no image) . I am using uib-carousal . Any solution?

```
 <div uib-carousal active = 'active'>
    <div uib-slide ng-repeat ="slide in slides">
          <img ng-src = {{slide.image}}>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: They have got a nice plunker in uib-carousel documentation. Refer to that. https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Comment: can you provide us with a *live link* or *fiddle*.?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/87STP95huIilfUTeFyNt?p=preview

Comment: see above fiidel want to hide slide id == 0 in xs view